# mutableGroups and mutableDetails in Stash

Tags: bitbucket-server

What are mutableGroups and mutableDetials in Stash or Bitbucket used for?

[image: Example code anippet]

Comment: Is is related to Atlassian Stash - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket_Server_(software)? Use [atlassian-stash] tag then

Comment: I couldn’t find a tag like ‘atlassian-stash’. So I had to use ‘git-stash’ as the tag. Yeah, this is related to Atlassian Statsh. In the wikinURL you shared, I couldn’t get any reference for the mutableGroups or mutableDetails.

Comment: This tag is a synonym for Bitbucket Server, which is a new name for Atlassian Stash